# Unable to run the code inside -Command switch using powershell.exe

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell code which I am calling via `powershell.exe`. The code does some validation and then calls the main script to do the actual job.

Below is the code:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command {
    $trademark = 'MMFSL'
    $product = 'OSHardening'
    $version = '3.0'

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    #Checks if the current powershell session is running in Administrative Mode
    $currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    if (!($currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Please run the file using Run as Administrator', "$($trademark)-$($product)-v$($version)", 'Ok', 'Error')
        break;
    }

    Expand-Archive -Path .\Windows.zip -DestinationPath $env:ProgramData\$($trademark)\$($product)\$($version) -Force

    Set-Location -Path $env:ProgramData\$($trademark)\$($product)\$($version)

    .\main.ps1
}
```

Below is the error message:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command {
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace
```

Comment: Where are you running it from?  Outside of powershell, it would have to be on line line.  You can run a script instead.

Comment: I think, he puts this stuff in a batch file and wants to start it by double-clicking it (or right-click, run as administrator)

Comment: @RonnyKaufmann "It would have to be on one line." that should say.

Comment: What does main.ps1 look like? The error message clearly states that you are not properly closing a script block. Is that issue in main.ps1?

Comment: Yes, I am running the code from a batch file. If possible can you please help me format the code in one line. Really appreciate. The main.ps1 contains the code for real operation to be performed. It's nothing but a Windows form application.

Comment: Why don't you put the code in a script then run the script?

Comment: Just use semicolons and put all the lines together.

Comment: @js2010 I tried running via -File parameter using a ps1 file. It works well. I just want to avoid this considering my execution environment.

Comment: Thanks @js2010, after formatting the code in semicolon's, the code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JS2010; I formatted the code into a single line by adding semicolons (;). Also, added the code under `"& { code }"`

Below is the modified code:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {$trademark = 'MMFSL';$product = 'OSHardening';$version = '3.0';Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;$PCWD = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).PartOfDomain;if($PCWD -eq $true){[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('This is application is supported on Workgroup/Non-Domain Joined computers only.', "$($trademark) + '-' + $($product) + '-v' + $($version)", 'Ok', 'Error');break;}elseif ($PCWD -eq $false){Expand-Archive -Path .\Windows.zip -DestinationPath $env:ProgramData\$($trademark)\$($product)\$($version) -Force;Set-Location -Path $env:ProgramData\$($trademark)\$($product)\$($version);Invoke-Expression -Command .\main.ps1;}}"
```